# Edit files on ckeditor

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm developing a php application that has to be able to browse the server, edit any file with CKEditor and save it.

The default CKEditor toolbar doesn't allow to open a file to edit. It has not the open-file button.

Any idea or link which could help me.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using pgrfilemanager. http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/ looks better but uses EditArea instead of Ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

Top google hit [file manager](http://labs.corefive.com/2009/10/30/an-open-file-manager-for-ckeditor-3-0/) for ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you missed CKEditor's brother plugin, [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/).

Ok, i've understood your problem. AFAIK there's no out-of-the-box solution for this but you can easily feed CKEditor's editor area with some javascript. When you hit the button for select the desired file, you'll need to load it's contents to the editor.